# PHP DateTime class accepts @{$timestamp} as a timestamp. why?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm wondered why PHP DateTime class accepts a strange value to represent the timestamp?

The stranger value is `@{$timestamp}`:

Example:

`$timestamp = time();
$date = new DateTime("@{$timestamp}");`

PHP's Manual does not show any information related to `@{$timestamp}`!!

Please note that it's not possible to do something like this:
`$date = new DateTime(time());`

I know the easiest way to set a timestamp for DateTime class is: `$date->setTimeStamp(time());` but I'm asking about `@{$timestamp}`

Does anyone know what is the magic behind `@{$timestamp}`?

Comment: `$date = new DateTime();` would be the equivalent of the invalid `$date = new DateTime(time());` because the default is the current time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `@timestamp` is [documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) under `Date/Time`>`Supported Date and Time Formats`>`Compound Formats`>`Localized Notations`

```
Description    Format           Examples

Unix Timestamp "@" "-"? [0-9]+ "@1215282385"
```